# Trying to get my python script to see if the text file reads only numbers or words

Tags: python-3.x, numbers, words

```
userinput = raw_input('Write file name:')

myfile = open(userinput)

content = myfile.read()

if content == "":
    print("Empty file")
elif content.isalpha():
    print("Just letters")
elif content.isdigit():
    print("Numbers")
else:
    print("It's both")
```

-When I do this and write text file that only have numbers I always get It's both and I don't know what to change. Also if anyone could help my when the script has found if the file only contains letters or number I need to find mean,median,min,max and standard deviation for the numbers how should I do that?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You are not accounting for newlines or spaces:

```
In [65]: "abc\n".isalpha()
Out[65]: False

In [66]: "133\n".isdigit()
Out[66]: False

In [67]: "133 123".isdigit()
Out[67]: False
```

If the data is a single line with no spaces use `content.rstrip()`:

```
In [70]: "abc\n".rstrip().isalpha()
Out[70]: True
```

If there are space then you will have to decide what you consider alpha or all digits, you can split and rejoin into a string without spaces or use `str.translate` to replace various whitespace with an empty string.

Another option is to use `all` with `str.isspace`:

```
In [72]: content = "123 123\n"

In [73]: all(ch.isdigit() or ch.isspace() for ch in content)
Out[73]: True

In [74]: content = "foo\nbar\n"

In [75]: all(ch.isalpha() or ch.isspace() for ch in content)
Out[75]: True
```

what you choose completely depends on what you consider qualifies as being either alpha or all digits i.e do multiple lines separated by newlines and /or whitespace qualify or does only consecutive characters on a single line with no whitespace.  Either way you will have to remove any trailing newlines or you will always reach your else.

If you are going down the all route or to work for very large files we can do it without reading all the file into memory:

```
import os


def check_type(user_input):
    if os.stat(user_input ).st_size == 0:
        return "Empty file"
    with open(user_input) as my_file:
        if all(ch.isdigit() or ch.isspace() for line in my_file for ch in line):
            return  "digits!"
        my_file.seek(0)
        if all(ch.isdigit() or ch.isspace() for line in my_file for ch in line):
            return "Alpha"
        return "Both"
```

Then to check if the file is all digits and calculate the average:

```
from collections import Counter
user_input = raw_input('Write file name:')
if check_type(user_input) == "Digits":
    with open(user_input) as f:
        nums = Counter(float(n) for line in f for n in line.split())
        print("Average = {}".format(sum(k*v for k,v in nums.items()) / sum(nums.values())))
```

The std dev and median I will leave for your self to figure out.

Comment: Thanks! When I try to write this I get an Error saying that I can't have : between In[] and content?

Comment: @Ella, you must be doing something wrong as the code in the answer and output are run from an ipython session, there should be no error

Comment: @Ella, you also have the question tagged python3 but you are using python2's raw_input so what are you actually using?